# C++ No matching constructor when using inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, curly-braces

I have code like this:

```cpp
class A{
public:
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    A a{.b = 5};
}
```

And the program compiles.

However, when I add another class and I make A inherit  that class (like below), it throws an error "no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’" (or "No matching constructor for initialization of A").

```cpp
class C{

};

class A: public C{
public:
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    A a{.b = 5};
}
```

Why?

Comment: Change `class A: C{` to `class A: public C{` - aggregate initialization requires that all inheritance is public

Comment: The program still doesn't compile (with the same error). I edited the code in my initial post to add public (that new program still doesn't compile).

Comment: Which compiler? On some [can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/z9eTvb). Designated initializes are available since C++20. So please provide compiler platform and compiler options.

Comment: Compiles with `-std=c++17` but not `-std=c++11`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using feature "[Designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers)" which is available since C++20.

Also I can't reproduce this issue: https://godbolt.org/z/fz3PeP

- note with C++17 gcc and clang just file an warning, msvc file an error
- with C++20 it is fine on all three (msvc needs `c++latest` option).
- with C++14 it files error everywhere

So looks like problem is just compiler version or configuration